# Can socket send / recv return errno 27 (EFBIG) on Solaris?

Tags: c, solaris

Can socket send / recv set errno 27 (EFBIG) on Solaris? Under which condition this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`man recv`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1466/recv-3socket.html#scrolltoc) doesn't document `EFBIG` meaning that if you see it, you have encountered a bug in the OS. Contact the <del>Sun</del> Oracle Solaris support.

If you are on the OpenSolaris, [the dumb search](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/search?v=OPENSOLARIS&string=EFBIG) reveals that sockets themselves do not return `EFBIG` (no matches under `sys/common/inet/`; compare e.g. with search for `ENOBUFS`). To me that tells that you might:

- have a parameter exceeding some safety limit. e.g. classical `-1u` bytes which would be caught even before reaching the sockets API. (unlikely for that other error codes are used.)
- use send/recv on a wrong socket/file descriptor.